# Store game score into sqlite database java

Tags: java, sqlite

I am trying to store the game score in a SQLite database.I created a table SCORE and the field HIGHSCORE in DB Browser.In the Game class I call the following method after the game ends

```
private void Add(int highScore) {
    try {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:score.db");
        c.setAutoCommit(false);
        stmt = c.createStatement();
        String sql = " INSERT INTO SCORE (HIGHSCORE) " +
                "VALUES (highScore);"+highScore;
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
        stmt.close();
        c.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
        System.exit(0);
    }
    System.out.println("Score registred");
}
```

And this is the error: java.sql.SQLException: no such column: highScore

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing the parameter correctly. 
Change to this:

```
    Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
    c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:score.db");
    c.setAutoCommit(false);
    String sql = "INSERT INTO SCORE (HIGHSCORE) VALUES (?);";
    PreparedStatement stmt = c.prepareStatement(sql);
    stmt.setInt(1, highScore);
    stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
    stmt.close();
    c.close();
```

This way you pass the parameter `highScore` to the sql statement.